# Avoid check-ins on a closed workitem in TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, checkin

id like to add a checkin policy to my solution.
i dont want any developer to check-in on a closed workitem.
is it possible to define a check-in policy that says checkin can only be made on a workitem on "state different than closed"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can if you install the power tools. They add a query policy. You can create and chose any query...

Answer (score 0):

"Work-Item Associations" worked, thank you anyway.